# Feedparser.py in root directory but still not working on dev server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, feedparser

I have the feedparser.py in my project directory but my code does not work on the local google dev server for google app engine.

I get this error,

```
  File "/home/ahmad/GAE/livemetals/lv.py", line 34, in <module>
    d = feedparser.parse(url)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'
INFO     2012-06-23 16:13:25,891 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

this is the code i'm using

```
url = "http://www.mysite.com"

d = feedparser.parse(url)
articles = {}
for row in d.entries:
    temp = [row['link'].encode('utf-8'),row['title'].encode('utf-8'),row['summary'].encode('utf-8')]
    articles.append(temp)
```

I can use feedparser on a non-google app engine python script. However when i copy "feedparser.py" i still can't get it to work in my project even though i import it as folows

```
import feedparser
```

How do I get feedparser to work in my GAE project? thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the GAE python runtime is finding another `feedparser` module.
Do you have another  `feedparser.py` script in your project?
I would try to print the `feedparser.__file__` to check where the module your project is pointing to.

Comment: I tried that and I get this, /home/ahmad/GAE/livemetals/feedparser/__init__.py
so it is pointing to my current project directory

Comment: oh nvm, I had a folder called "feedparser", i just deleted it and now its pointing to /home/ahmad/GAE/livemetals/feedparser.py
and i don't get my error! Thanks for your help, it worked!