# Feedparser doesn't work, gives AttributeError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, feedparser

I have this code:

```
import jinja2
import webapp2
import os
from google.appengine.ext import db
import feedparser
from xml.dom import minidom
from google.appengine.api import memcache

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)

class News(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    url = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    imageurl = db.StringProperty(required=True)

feeds = [   'https://news.google.co.in/news/section?cf=all&pz=1&ned=in&topic=e&ict=ln&output=rss'   # Entertainment
        'https://news.google.co.in/news/section?cf=all&pz=1&ned=in&topic=snc&ict=ln&output=rss' # Science
        'https://news.google.co.in/news/section?cf=all&pz=1&ned=in&topic=s&ict=ln&output=rss'   # Sports
        'https://news.google.co.in/news/section?cf=all&pz=1&ned=in&topic=b&ict=ln&output=rss'   # Business
        'https://news.google.co.in/news/section?cf=all&pz=1&ned=in&topic=tc&ict=ln&output=rss'  # Technology
]

def render_str(template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(feedparser.__file__)
        self.response.write(render_str('mainpage.html'))

class Entertainment(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        rssfeed = feedparser.parse(feeds[0])
        self.response.write(rsfeed.entries[0].title)
        self.response.write(rsfeed.entries[0].link)
        self.response.write(rsfeed.entries[0].published)
        self.response.write(rsfeed.entries[0].description)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/entertainment', Entertainment)
                            ], debug = True)
```

`mainpage.html` has nothing except five `<p></p>` tags with one of them hyperlinked to `/entertainment`.

When I run it and click on the hyperlinked paragraph, I get this

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'`

I've followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171073/feedparser-py-in-root-directory-but-still-not-working-on-dev-server), which is why I printed out the filepath in the `get` of `MainPage`.

My folder structure is :

- templates

  - mainpage.html
- app.yaml
- feedparser.py
- newsapp.py
- newsapp.pyc

When I ran it the first time, feedparser pointed to `C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Downloads\7c\News Aggregator GAE\feedparser.pyc`. That was wrong, so I deleted the `.pyc` file, and then it pointed to `C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Downloads\7c\News Aggregator GAE\feedparser.py`. But it still gave the same error and the `.pyc` file got generated again. I know it gets generated because I'm compiling the feedparser file, but why does the feedparser module point to that location? And how can I get around that error?

Comment: How so you "run it"? (and what does "it" mean?)

Comment: "it" is newsapp.py. I run it through Windows Powershell

Answer (score 0):

The GAE app code is not necessarily able to run as a standalone application.

The proper way to execute it locally is through the SDK's local development server, see  [Using the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-local-server).

The local development server will properly set the execution environment to not accidentally reach modules outside your application. It should address your import issue.

Comment: When I do `dev_appserver.py newsapp` in Powershell while located in the folder, it just opens the `dev_appserver.py` file in my editor. Nothing else happens and localhost:8080 shows unable to connect.

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ powershell, seems it may be a tad too smart. Try it in a regular terminal. This *might* also help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33132299/4495081

Comment: Same thing. Never mind. I'll move onto Flask. Hopefully the import problems won't be there.

Comment: Also, the `newsapp` argument is not OK. I'd maybe try `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` or some other invocation as needed - check the docs.

Comment: Got the problem. My `feedparser.py` file wasn't right. It works now.